# Using the Watson SDK To Do Continuous Speech To Text

Tags: websocket, speech-to-text, ibm-watson, libwebsockets

I have previously been using the IBM Watson speech to text service to transcribe full audio files that have been pre-recorded. However, I am now trying to do live transcription while using the speaker identification feature. This means that I cannot send each short file (recording audio in about 30 second chunks) individually since the context of the speakers has to be maintained. How can I do this while still utilizing Python?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use WebSocket for real-time transcription. You pass in a chunk of audio and Watson responds with a transcription. You just need to detect the silence to break the stream up into chunks.

You also need to specify the language to be used for the transcription, and it's better when the source audio is coming from a phone call, you should use the *Narrow Band models* for the best results.

> IBM® recommends that you use the broadband model for responsive,
>   real-time applications (for example, for live-speech applications).
>   [Reference](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/speech-to-text/input.html#input).

You can check one full example using Python with Watson STT in Python in this [link](https://github.com/nexmo-community/voice-watson-speechtotext). This example uses Nexmo, but you can get the logic for using in any application for real-time transcripts.

- [Pass-to-pass](https://www.nexmo.com/blog/2017/10/03/real-time-call-transcription-ibm-watson-python-dr/) with Watson Speech to Text - Real transcription (Python).
- Official documentation of [IBM Watson Speech to Text](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/speech-to-text/).

Comment: this is a full example using python to talk to Watson STT via Websockets: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-to-text-websockets-python, There is a function that pushes the audio from the file over the websocket one chunk at a time, you can do just the same thing, but with the chunks coming from the microphone 

more examples can be found here: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/